# Orbeon, OpenSSO and session expiration

Tags: session, orbeon, opensso

We are using Orbeon 3.9 in separate deployment (cross context), application security is with OpenSSO, server is glassfish.

Note: Orbeon submissions (backrequests) is handled with another web-application with contex accessible only from localhost and not under OpenSSO.

After session timeout expiration (left opened form in browser long enough for timeout) is Orbeon stuck in "Loading..." loop right after first "click".

As Firebug says:

1) Orbeon ajax POST-requesting for /application-context/orbeon/xforms-server

2) OpenSSO stops this request with 302 Moved Temporarily

3) ajax is GET-requesting /opensso/cdcservlet?...

4) returned 200, probably login page content

5) response was ignored, goto 1)

Endlessly.

I have tried this: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/other/redirect-users-error

But didn't helped, because dialog is not shown.

We need to redirect browser to that login page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written, if you want Orbeon Forms client-side code to recognize the answer from the server as an error, the server also needs to have in the body of the HTTP response a document that looks like:

```
<error>
    <title>...</title>
    <body>...</body>
</error>
```

If such a document isn't present, then the client-side code will retry the request after a delay, and show that "Loading…" in the meantime. So in your case, you would need to find a way to get the login page to answer with that document if the request was redirected from an Ajax request.

Now, I also think that Orbeon Forms should be improved in this respect, and should consider a 302 answer to an Ajax request as an error, either by default, or allowing you to configure this behavior. For this reason, I opened [issue #560](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/560).